# TFS How to enable the confirmation dialog pop when undoing pending changes in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am following this blog post:
[TFS Pending Changes – Ignoring Files which are Identical to the Originals](http://thesoftwarecondition.com/blog/2011/05/01/tfs-pending-changes-ignoring-files-which-are-identical-to-the-originals/)

But I do not get the dialogue shown in step 3 which asked for confirmation regarding the undo.  Where can I turn this on within visual studio?

Comment: Do you have any modified files?

Answer (score 2):

Please do not do this.

I loathe the advice given to you in this blog post.  It is super dangerous to get into the habit of asking the system to undo all your changes and then hitting no to not *actually* undo your changes.  You fat finger this one time and accidentally click "yes to all" and you have lost all your work.  Oops!

I think that you will be much happier and much safer if you simply let the system do this work for you instead of relying upon a workaround to make this work:

Simply use [`tfpt uu`](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f) or `tf uu` to undo unchanged files.

Comment: of course, its diabolical that you are using a SCM that thinks unchanged files are changed in the first place.

Comment: @gbjbaanb Obviously it's a performance optimization.  Your source control system can determine that files are checked out or changed in one of two ways:  either *you* can tell it, or *it* can scan your filesystem.  If you have a giant source tree (think Windows or Visual Studio) then this could be horribly slow.  If you have a more reasonably sized source tree then TFS supports either an edit/merge/commit model ("Local Workspaces") or, of course, git.

Comment: Yes, but TFS should have the capability to automatically exclude non-changes from check-ins via the UI. It's rather ludicrous that devs have to micro-manage this aspect of development - SCMs should empower their users, not get in their way

Comment: @NathanPitman: TFS will not accept "non-changes".  Any changes that you try to checkin that contain no content changes will be automatically undone.  Or you could use Local Workspaces, where this happens automatically.

Comment: Perhaps this is a feature in a newer version of TFS? Non-changes previously were included in check-ins, which is why people in the past have gone to great efforts to purge them. And local workspaces are only a TFS2012 feature - though it's good to see that Microsoft is finally changing this... using readonly attributes to track check out state was an awful idea.

Comment: @NathanPitman: in all versions of TFS, if you check-out a file and attempt to check it in unchanged, it will not be included in the resultant changeset.  If *all* files are unmodified, then you will get an error when you attempt to check-in, as it's a no-op.

Comment: @EdwardThomson: Funny... both my colleague and I are adamant that we've managed to check in no-ops in the past, but when we try to replicate it now, we cannot. However, there is one situation I can think of which results in no-ops being checked in - when you create a child branch, rename the child and then merge all changesets back to the parent.

Comment: @NathanPitman: I have only run through this scenario in my head -- I *think* what's happening here is that it's checking in the merge, so that it marks that a merge has been completed for that changeset.  In this case, it should show that you have no unmerged changesets, and it should not include that changeset in future merges from the child to the parent.  This is admittedly pretty simplistic, I admit; why not just filter that change out *anyway*, you might be asking.  I suspect it's to avoid future merge computations, but that's just a guess.